# What Happened to UnitPrice in Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Sorry, this gets curiouser and curiouser: I just updated my IPP in NuGet (VS2010) and now the UnitPrice property has disappeared from Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item. It's in the SDK Docs and it's in the online docs, just not in the DLL.

I'll always admit it COULD be me, but I'd sure like to know how. :)

Any help appreciated (I'll submit a Support Ticket on Monday if I can't get this straightened out over the weekend).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item item = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Item();

//Set UnitPrice
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Money unitPrice = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Money();
unitPrice.Amount = 22;
unitPrice.AmountSpecified = true;
item.Item1 = unitPrice;
```

Comment: Hi Peter: Item1???? How does IDS know this is the UnitPrice? And what happened to item.UnitPrice that is in the SDK docs? Inquiring minds want to know. :) Thanks.

Comment: OK, after double-checking the SDK docs (in which UnitPrice exists but Item1 doesn't) and then trying VS Intellisense (which recognizes Item1 but not UnitPrice) I will defer to your authority and henceforth use "Item1" in place of "UnitPrice" when dealing with QBD Items. Thanks for the "inside scoop".